# Installing Istio in Kubernetes with automatic sidecar injection: istio-inializer.yaml Validation Failure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, microservices, kubectl, istio

I'm trying to install Istio with automatic sidecar injection into Kubernetes. My environment consists of three masters and two nodes and was built on Azure using the Azure Container Service marketplace product.

Following the documentation located [here](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/automatic-sidecar-inject.html), I have so far enabled `RBAC` and `DynamicAdmissionControl`. I have accomplished this by modifying `/etc/kubernetes/istio-inializer.yaml` on the Kubernetes Master by adding the [following content outlined in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA4Bo.png) and then restarting the Kubernetes Master using the Unix command, `reboot`.

The next step in the documentation is to apply the yaml using `kubectl`. I assume that the documentation intends for the user to clone the Istio repository and `cd` into it before this step but that is unmentioned.

```
git clone https://github.com/istio/istio.git
cd istio
kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/istio-initializer.yaml
```

After which the following error occurs:

```
user@hostname:~/istio$ kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/istio-initializer.yaml

configmap "istio-inject" configured
serviceaccount "istio-initializer-service-account" configured
error: error validating "install/kubernetes/istio-initializer.yaml": error validating data: found invalid field initializers for v1.ObjectMeta; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

If I attempt to execute `kubectl apply` with the mentioned flag, `validate=false`, then this error is generated instead:

```
user@hostname:~/istio$ kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/istio-initializer.yaml --validate=false

configmap "istio-inject" configured
serviceaccount "istio-initializer-service-account" configured
deployment "istio-initializer" configured
error: unable to recognize "install/kubernetes/istio-initializer.yaml": no matches for admissionregistration.k8s.io/, Kind=InitializerConfiguration
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. The problem appears to be related to the `admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1` block in the `yaml` but I'm unsure what specifically is incorrect in this block.

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: InitializerConfiguration
metadata:
  name: istio-sidecar
initializers:
  - name: sidecar.initializer.istio.io
    rules:
      - apiGroups:
          - "*"
        apiVersions:
          - "*"
        resources:
          - deployments
          - statefulsets
          - jobs
          - daemonsets
```

Installed version of Kubernetes:

```
user@hostname:~/istio$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.6", GitCommit:"7fa1c1756d8bc963f1a389f4a6937dc71f08ada2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-06-16T18:21:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.6", GitCommit:"7fa1c1756d8bc963f1a389f4a6937dc71f08ada2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-06-16T18:21:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I suspect this is a versioning mismatch. As a follow up question, is it possible to deploy a version of kubernetes >= 1.7.4 to Azure using ACS?

I'm fairly new to working with Kubernetes so if anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a versioning problem as the alpha feature is supported for k8s version> 1.7 as mentioned here (https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/extensible-admission-controllers/#what-are-initializers).

> 1.7 introduces two alpha features, Initializers and External Admission
>   Webhooks, that address these limitations. These features allow admission 
>   controllers to be developed out-of-tree and configured at runtime.

And it is possible to deploy a version of kubernetes >= 1.7.4 to Azure. Note sure about the deployed version using the portal. But if you use acs-egnine to generate the ARM template, it is possible to deploy a cluster with version 1.7.5.

You can refer here for the procedures https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine. Basically it involves three steps. First, you should create the json file by referring to the clusterDefinition section. To use version 1.7.5, you should specify the attribute "orchestratorRelaease" to be "1.7" and also enable the RBAC by specifying the attribute "enableRbac" to be true. Second, use the acs engine (version >= 0.6.0) to parse the json file to ARM template (azuredeploy.json & azuredeploy.parameters.json should be created). Lastly, use the command "New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment" in powershell to deploy the cluster to Azure.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Marked as answer.